# Связь физических lan портов в виртуальном коммутаторе Open vSwitch

Tags: linux, сеть, виртуализация, коммутатор

Имеется железо (сервер на linux), в котором присутствует 2 физических lan порта. Один порт подключен к основной локальной сети, а второй должен подключиться к видеосерверу. 
Необходимо, чтобы сервер мог выполнить роль виртуального коммутатора и передавать информацию полученную на одном порту в другой.

Установил приложение Open vSwitch.
При установке создался виртуальный коммутатор (Bridge ovs0) с портом ovs0, добавил в коммутатор физические порты eno1 и eno2, после этого пропала связь с сервером по ssh и сервер стал невиден в локальной сети.

Сервер использует для связи с локальной сетью порт eno1, на котором настроена статика.

Удаляя порт eno1 из виртуального коммутатора, сервер начинал снова определяться в сети!

Нашёл пример конфигурации файла /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto ovs0

allow-ovs ovs0 
iface ovs0 inet manual   
ovs_type OVSBridge   
ovs_ports eth0 ovs0-vlan2 ovs0-vlan3 ovs0-vlan4

allow-ovs0 eth0 
iface eth0 inet manual   
ovs_type OVSPort   
ovs_bridge ovs0   
ovs_options vlan_mode=native-untagged tag=2 trunks=2,3,4

allow-ovs0 
ovs0-vlan2 
iface ovs0-vlan2 inet static   
ovs_bridge ovs0   
ovs_type OVSIntPort   
ovs_options tag=2   
address 169.254.254.1   
netmask 255.255.255.0 

allow-ovs0 ovs0-vlan3 
iface ovs0-vlan3 inet dhcp   
ovs_bridge ovs0   
ovs_type OVSIntPort   
ovs_options tag=3

allow-ovs0 ovs0-vlan4 
iface ovs0-vlan4 inet static   
ovs_bridge ovs0   
ovs_type OVSIntPort   
ovs_options tag=4   
address 0.0.0.0   
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Подскажите, как можно отконфигурировать /etc/network/interfaces, чтобы нормально работала сеть?

Написал это:

```
# The primary network interface
auto ovs0
allow-ovs0 ovs0
iface ovs0 inet manual
  ovs_type OVSBridge
  ovs_ports eno1 eno2

auto eno1
allow-ovs0 eno1
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.168.10.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.10.253
dns-nameservers 192.168.10.1
ovs_bridge ovs0
ovs_type OVSIntPort

auto eno2
allow-ovs0 eno2
iface eno2 inet manual
ovs_type OVSPort
ovs_bridge ovs0
```

Теперь хоть есть связь с основным сервером по статическому IP(eno1). Но в локальной сети видеосервера, подключенного к eno2, не видно!

Comment: Стреляете из пушки по воробушкам. Просто засуньте оба порта в бридж - этого будет достаточно.

Comment: @ gbg, как-то так?
 
auto ovs0
allow-ovs0 ovs0
iface ovs0 inet manual
  ovs_type OVSBridge
  ovs_ports eno1 eno2

Comment: @gbg, я просто далёк от сетевого администрирования и терминов) По хорошему нужно понять принцип сего происходящего. 
Я так понимаю необходимо добавить сетевое подключение мост (как выше), статическое подключение внутреннего OVSIntPort порта (физический порт локальной сети основного сервера), и внешний OVSPort (физический порт подключения видеосервера). Верно?

Comment: @gbg, может гляните, добавил информацию в вопрос, и подскажете чего? учитывая, что вы единственный, кто прокомментировал мой вопрос
ps. просто бридж из двух портов не работает..

Answer (score 0):

В общем, пробами, экспериментами нашёл такое решение для своей задачи:
засунул оба физических порта в бридж + добавил vlan (оно же виртуальное подключение моего текущего главного сервера). Прописал такой конфиг в /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto ovs0
allow-ovs0 ovs0
iface ovs0 inet manual
  ovs_type OVSBridge
  ovs_ports eno1 eno2 vlan1

auto eno1
allow-ovs0 eno1
iface eno1 inet manual
ovs_bridge ovs0
ovs_type OVSPort

auto eno2
allow-ovs0 eno2
iface eno2 inet manual
ovs_bridge ovs0
ovs_type OVSPort

auto vlan1
allow-ovns vlan1
iface vlan1 inet static
address 192.168.10.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.10.253
dns-nameservers 192.168.10.1
ovs_bridge ovs0
ovs_type OVSIntPort
```

Comment: Ну, ovs тут лишнее, а так - сойдет